# Order a space matrix by index

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have matrix space some locations 1, 2, 3, and 4

```
df<-matrix(data=c(0.00, 4.69, 12.63, 2.99, 4.69, 0.00, 17.30, 5.15, 12.63, 17.30, 0.00, 13.72, 2.99, 5.15, 13.72, 0.00), ncol=4) 
colnames(df)<-c(seq(1:4))
rownames(df)<-c(seq(1:4))
df

#    1     2     3     4
#1  0.00  4.69 12.63  2.99
#2  4.69  0.00 17.30  5.15
#3 12.63 17.30  0.00 13.72
#4  2.99  5.15 13.72  0.00
```

and I would like to order this matrix in descending order by rank of each space row, so get

```
#       1     2     3     4
#1      1     2     2     2 
#2      3     1     4     3 
#3      4     4     1     4 
#4      2     3     3     1
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rank` and as it is needed by each column, we loop through the columns (`apply` with `MARGIN=2`)

```
apply(df, 2, rank)
```

Comment: @Sotos Yeah, I write it differently :=)

Comment: I m not sure about efficiency of package `matrixstats`. Maybe I ll do some benchmarking when time permits

Comment: @Sotos it should be faster as it very specific for matrices

Comment: thaks for your clue, i get it with little modified iteration each row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colRanks` from `matrixstats` package, i.e.

```
library(matrixStats)

t(colRanks(df))
```

which gives,

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
> [1,]    1    2    2    2
> [2,]    3    1    4    3
> [3,]    4    4    1    4
> [4,]    2    3    3    1
> ```